How do I handle List of MyClass in Entity Framework
I tried many things many times and couldn't figure out what works and ended up X to Y problems.
I want implement
class ProductOrder
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}

internal class InwardLog 
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // Problem
    public List<ProductOrder> ProductOrdersList { get; set; }

    public string DateTime { get; set;}
    public int OperatorId { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set;}
    public decimal AmountPaid { get; set;}
    public string BillType { get; set; }
    public int? SupplierId { get; set; }
}

I want to access ProductOrdersList like this
var log = database.InwardLogs.Where(p => p.Id == SomeId).FirstOrDefault();
var list = log.ProductOrdersList;

ProductOrder doesn't have to be independent. it should only be accessed through Parent, and if cannot be that way I'm fine with it.
What do I need to do to make it work ?

How InwardLog is related to ProductOrder?

@JonasH Yes, your right. I updated access approach.

@SvyatoslavDanyliv InwardLog is just a detail of items that are incoming into a Shop and ProductOrder is a class that contains reference ProductId of incoming  products

When you encounter the problem of going from X to Y, do you have the relevant foreign keys or navigation relationships configured in dbcontex? Do you want to access the ProductOrdersList by searching the InwardLog object for someId?

What is the error you are getting? What exactly is "not working" and how?

Did you try with .Include( x=>x.ProductOrdersList ) in the query?

Your example seem to be very similar to the Blog/Post example in the EF introduction, just with different names, and other properties. Have you tried following the tutorial?


ProductOrder doesn't have to be independent. it should only be accessed through Parent, and if cannot be that way I'm fine with it.

If you don’t want to access the ProductOrder via the DBContext directly, you can remove the following DbSet from the DbContext
public DbSet<ProductOrder> ProductOrders { get; set; }
Then in the OnModelCreating method, you can use OwnsMany to indicate that ProductOrdersList is an owned entity of InwardLog. When query the data, use the Include method to ensure that ProductOrdersList is loaded, filter by Id using the Where method, and finally use FirstOrDefault to get the first matching record.
Here is a reference example：
Model：
public class ProductOrder
{
     public int ProductId { get; set; }
     public int Quantity { get; set; }
}

public class InwardLog
{
     [Key]
     public int Id { get; set; }

       
     public List<ProductOrder> ProductOrdersList { get; set; }

     public string DateTime { get; set; }
     public int OperatorId { get; set; }
     public string Note { get; set; }
     public decimal AmountPaid { get; set; }
     public string BillType { get; set; }
     public int? SupplierId { get; set; }
}

Dbcontext:
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
       

    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
    }
    public DbSet<InwardLog> InwardLogs { get; set; }
 
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.Entity<InwardLog>()
        .OwnsMany(i => i.ProductOrdersList);

    }
}

Method:
public IActionResult Privacy()
{
     int someId = 2;

            
         var log = _dbContext.InwardLogs
                           .Include(p => p.ProductOrdersList)
                           .Where(p => p.Id == someId)
                           .FirstOrDefault();

         var list = log.ProductOrdersList;

              
         return View(list);
            
 }



I think you'll need to properly configure the entity relationships in EF... you can try like that:
public class ProductOrder
{
    public int Id { get; set; } // Primary key
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    // Foreign key to InwardLog
    public int InwardLogId { get; set; }
    public InwardLog InwardLog { get; set; }
}

Then
internal class InwardLog
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // Navigation property
    public List<ProductOrder> ProductOrdersList { get; set; } = new List<ProductOrder>();

    public string DateTime { get; set; }
    public int OperatorId { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }
    public decimal AmountPaid { get; set; }
    public string BillType { get; set; }
    public int? SupplierId { get; set; }
}

for the context:
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<InwardLog> InwardLogs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ProductOrder> ProductOrders { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        // Configure one-to-many relationship
        modelBuilder.Entity<InwardLog>()
            .HasMany(il => il.ProductOrdersList)
            .WithOne(po => po.InwardLog)
            .HasForeignKey(po => po.InwardLogId);
    }
}

Hope it will help!

I get the part where you added int InwardLogId but I don't get InwardLog InwardLog in ProductOrder why recursive ? and can you or someone explain me what is happening in OnModelCreating I'm new to EF.

It is explicitly configuring a 1-to-many relation. The property is not "recursive",  it just has the same name as its type.

@Fildor My bad confusion, "why recursive ?", by that I mean why InwardLog -> ProductOrder -> InwardLog.

It's just a navigation property. EF won't create a circle ref in the db. (Usually)

Denis's answer works for storing but not accessing.
EF uses either of Eager loading, Lazy loading or Explicit loading as mentioned in EF Docs to improve fetch speed resulting skipping of nested or inner level data.
If you have Entities that consist inner level of data like in my case List<SomeClass> then you need to explicitly specify EF to include inner level data by doing the following:
var innerContent = dbContext.YourEntityCollection.Include(p => p.InnerContent).YourOperations

which was in my case:
var log = database.InwardLogs.Include(p => p.ProductOrdersList).Where(p => p.Id == SomeId).FirstOrDefault();
var list = log.ProductOrdersList;

